# need query on below regexp in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

```
COLUMN_A
---------------------------

MYSQL/SQL
MYSQL/SQL/ORACLE
MYSQL/SQL/ORACLE/TOAD
MYSQL/SQL/ORACLE/TOAD/PLSQL
MYSQLSQLORACLE -PLSQL
```

I am expecting below output:

```
COLUMN_B                               COLUMN_C
----------------------                 ------------------- 
MYSQL                                   SQL
SQL                                     ORACLE
SQL                                     ORACLE/TOAD
SQL                                     ORACLE/TOAD/PL/SQL
MYSQLSQLORACLE -PLSQL                   NULL
```

Logic:

1. if `column_a` values contain one slash then put before slash value into `coulmn_b` and after salsh put value into `column_c`
2. if `column_a` values contain 2 slashes then put alter first slash value into `coulmn_b` and after 2nd salsh put value into `column_c`

Comment: Looks like some kind of a *hierarchy* data, but - unformatted, it is difficult to read and guess what is what. Could you, please, fix that and explain - in plain English - rules which lead from input to output?

Comment: 1. if column_a values contain one slash then put before slash value into coulmn_b and after salsh put value into column_c

Comment: 2. if column_a values contain 2slashes then put alter first slash value into coulmn_b and after 2nd salsh put value into column_c

Answer (score 3):

Seems you want to extract depending on the word `ORACLE` for `column_B`, and on the word `SQL` for `column_C`. So, Consider using :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A,'[^/]+',1,3)='ORACLE' 
            THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A,'[^/]+',1,2)
            ELSE REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A,'[^/]+')
             END AS column_B,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(column_A,'/') > 0 
            THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(column_A,'(.*SQL/)(\S+)(.*)','\2',1,1) 
             END AS column_C
  FROM tab;

  COLUMN_B              COLUMN_C
  --------------------- ---------------------
  MYSQL                 SQL
  SQL                   ORACLE
  SQL                   ORACLE/TOAD
  SQL                   ORACLE/TOAD/PLSQL
  MYSQLSQLORACLE -PLSQL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce3b1cd0a7f2c9d218327794d30a0037)</kbd>

**Update :** Depending on the rules within the later update, you can use

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT column_A,
        CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(column_A,'/') = 0
             THEN column_A
             WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(column_A,'/') = 1
             THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A,'[^/]+')
             ELSE REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A,'[^/]+',1,2)
              END AS column_B
   FROM tab   
)
SELECT  column_B,
        CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(column_A,'/') = 1
             THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A,'[^/]+$')
             WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(column_A,'/') > 1
             THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(column_A,'(.*'||column_B||'/)(\S+)(.*)','\2',1,1) 
              END AS column_C
  FROM t;

  COLUMN_B              COLUMN_C
  --------------------- ---------------------
  MYSQL                 SQL
  SQL                   ORACLE
  SQL                   ORACLE/TOAD
  SQL                   ORACLE/TOAD/PLSQL
  MYSQLSQLORACLE -PLSQL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fcc4c0ec90549fc791ab3a6ee730a53b)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Your logic appears to be:

```
SELECT column_A,
       (CASE WHEN column_A like '%/%/%'
             THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A, '[^/]+', 1, 2)
             ELSE REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A, '[^/]+', 1, 1)
        END) AS column_B,
       (CASE WHEN column_A like '%/%/%'
             THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(column_A, '^[^/]+/[^/]+/(.*)$', '\1')
             ELSE REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_A, '[^/]+', 1, 2)
        END) AS column_C
FROM tab;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f4f069f36dfad7259b006270647bc1a0) is a db<>fiddle.